# How to connect my server to external world

Tags: windows, apache, postgresql, jboss

I am working with database project for that I installed postgresSql, jboss and apache 2.4 in windows 7. I am able to get data from postgresql to jboss server then using apache(localhost:80) able to get data in browser within LAN. Now I want to connect this server to external world. Other people could access my server from browser. How to make my server to available for external server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may edit the pg_hba.conf file